# Embedded UITableView not reloading with reloadData() on UIButtonClick in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reloaddata

I am trying to get my table view to update when I add a new cell to my SQLite Table. However, as of now, when I add a new cell to the SQLite Table and call reloadData, nothing updates or happens. My UITableView is embedded into my Main View Controller so that might be part of the issue. I also feel as if this may be an issue with the `tableView.dataSource` or something. I am not sure. I am very new to swift.

I have tried calling the reloadData from the UITableViewController file and from the UIViewController which contains the button that is supposed to add data and then update the Table. Neither have worked. I also tried to substitute it with `tableView?.beginUpdates()` and `tableView?.endUpdates()`

My button code (part of button script):

```swift
    @IBAction func addTask(_ sender: Any) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZZZZZ"

        let taskDateFormatted = dateFormatter.string(from: taskDate.date)
        let newTask = Task(title: taskTitle.text!, description: descriptionTextView.text,
                           date: taskDateFormatted)
        let instSQLiteData = SQLiteData()
        let instTaskTableVC = TaskTableVC()

        instSQLiteData.uploadData(newTask.title, newTask.description, newTask.date)
        instTaskTableVC.taskTable?.reloadData()

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

My UITableViewController script/class (part of tableview script):

```swift
class TaskTableVC : UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var taskTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.taskTable.dataSource = self
        self.taskTable.delegate = self
    }
```

How my UITableViewController loads data (part of tableview script):

```swift
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let instSQLiteData = SQLiteData()
        return instSQLiteData.getRowCount()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let instSQLiteData = SQLiteData()

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = instSQLiteData.getTasksArray()[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
```

Once the button is pressed I just want the table to update but I cannot get it to work even though I have tried to follow a ton of other questions with the same topic. Much thanks!

Comment: I think this line missing or you haven't posted this code `instTaskTableVC.taskTable? = self.taskTable`

Comment: @Hisenberg What will that line do exactly?

Comment: You need to assign a tableview to `instTaskTableVC` instance. OR you can call `reloadData()` on `self.taskTable` instead of `instTaskTableVC.taskTable`

Comment: you need to pass the instance of taskTable class to the class which you have written the button action, and from that instance you need to call the tableView reload data

Comment: Unrelated but creating new instances of `SQLiteData` in  `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt` and get data is very, very expensive. Those methods are called very frequently.

Comment: I cannot assign ``instTaskTableVC.taskTable? = self.taskTable`` because ``self.taskTable`` is not defined in the button function. The button code and the UITableViewController are two different scripts.